# My screen blinks every 2 seconds

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I used Linux for quite a while and I never had this problem. My screen blinks every 1.5 second. I tried reinstalling Linux, changing my drivers (tried 495, xserver-xorg-video-nouveau and 460) and switching to integrated intel graphic card via x server settings. I also tried changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to something else in /etc/default/grub but it just made my gui stop working. It happens on an (almost) clean install. There are some problems in journalctl:

```
>journalctl -p 0..3

Jan 29 17:13:12 walenty-nitroan51544 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP4.WLAN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/dswload2-162)
Jan 29 17:13:12 walenty-nitroan51544 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20201113/psobject-220)
Jan 29 17:13:12 walenty-nitroan51544 kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: Unsupported power profile mode 0 on RENOIR
Jan 29 17:13:29 walenty-nitroan51544 sddm-helper[1171]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jan 29 17:13:31 walenty-nitroan51544 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
Jan 29 17:13:31 walenty-nitroan51544 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
Jan 29 17:13:31 walenty-nitroan51544 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
Jan 29 17:13:31 walenty-nitroan51544 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: tmr: stalled at ffffffffffffffff
```

This line repeats 20 times.

Those are my specs:

```
>dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii

ii  libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64                   470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-470                       470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-470:amd64                470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-470:i386                 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-470:amd64                 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-470:i386                  470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-470:amd64                 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-470:i386                  470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-470:amd64                  470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64                   470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-470:i386                    470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-470:amd64                     470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-470:i386                      470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64                   470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386                    470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-27-generic 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1       amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-27
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1       amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-470 for the generic-hwe-20.04 flavour
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.13.0-27-generic 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1       amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-27 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-27-generic  5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1       amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-27-generic
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-470                   470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-driver-470                          470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-470                   470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-470                   470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.16~0.20.04.1           all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-470                           470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470              470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2    amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Also tried using `xrandr` to set different refresh rate. It seems that rate 144.00 is causing the blinking. I changed the rate a few times back and forth from 144 and 60 and the blinking stopped. However, when I changed to 60 for the first time the blinking got less frequent but much stronger. It's weird.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution is to use xrandar twice - to change the refresh rate to anything and then to 144 which is the correct refresh rate.

```
> xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+  60.00  
   1680x1050    144.00  
   1280x1024    144.00  
   1440x900     144.00  
   1280x800     144.00  
   1280x720     144.00                                                                                                                                                                        
   1024x768     144.00                                                                                                                                                                        
   800x600      144.00                                                                                                                                                                        
   640x480      144.00       
> xrandr --output eDP-1-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60
> xrandr --output eDP-1-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144
```

For some reason this solved this problem. I'm adding those lines to my `.profile`